Trying to understand the exact math behind use of decoupling capacitors
From what I have read so far decoupling caps help in reducing the supply droop due to trace inductors in case the load draws large current transients. The capacitor works to supply the current demanded by load so that the inductor does not have to see current change across it. However, I don't understand how this works out by math of circuit analysis. Let's say I have the following circuit where IG is a changing current load. How does the inductor know that the current change is going to be supplied by the cap? How would you write the responses mathematically? I have tried to simulate this as well and I get the following waveforms which is even more confusing...


I also tried to solve it using laplace and I am not sure what is going wrong here??


Part of the function of decoupling capacitors is electromagnetic: rapid changes in current couple to other parts of the circuitry via magnetic fields. By encouraging such changes to follow a small loop around the component, bypass capacitors minimize this effect.

You're description is on the right track, but the model circuit is not realistic....you've analyzed mathematically an ideal LC tank circuit with a step current disturbance.  LC tank has resonant frequency of 1/(2pisqrt(LC)), so you tend to see oscillations in your simulation at this frequency.  But what you want to simulate/analyze is a power distribution circuit, which due to practical power supply and routing limitations has significant resistance and a small inductance, plus the bypass capacitors added near the load which have ESR and mounting inductance.

Here's a simulation with some more realistic values, and a fast current change.

Note that if you don't specify rise and fall times with a pulse signal, spice may default to a relatively slow value that is related to the pulse frequency. LTspice defaults to 10% of Ton or 10% of Tperiod-Ton, whichever is smaller.
I've specified 1ns, which is realistic for a fast CMOS gate. The current is 0/10mA. 30nH is roughly the inductance of a 20mm trace 1mm wide.
The series supply resistance is given as 10mΩ which is about the resistance of 40mm of 1mm wide trace.
Without the bypass capacitor (top trace) there are spike of more than 10% of the supply voltage in both directions. With more inductance or more current, the spikes can easily reach several volts.
With the bypass capacitor the variation is only a couple mV.
At some point using lumped elements as we are doing here is no longer valid, but even with some simple guesstimates we can get some idea of the value of having a low-ESR bypass capacitor near the IC power pins.

This answer is shows bypass cap impact in more realistic power distribution network circuit.  The voltage droop experienced at the load is perhaps even more clearly seen by simulating steady state followed by a single step in load current (0 to maybe 500mA), as mentioned with very fast rise time.  The next level in modelling would be to add series mounting inductance of the small bypass capacitors, example the smallest cap could be modelled as 1000pF with 500pH series inductance. The higher the frequency/fidelity of simulation, the greater the importance of parasitic effects in the PDN.

I understand that it works practically but can you help me in obtaining a mathematical result that convincingly proves this? Is my approach using Laplace transforms in the right direction?

You can use simulation or Laplace analysis but your model (and the parameters) have to reflect reality or you're just wasting your time. Simulation allows more complex models. What's actually happening here is that we're running into limitations of the lumped element model because nodes (Vcc/GND, for example) are no longer at the exact same potential. We can bandaid it by adding lumped inductance and capacitance, adding transmission lines and so on, but ultimately you'd want to use a field solver to get the most accurate results at very high frequencies.

That said, for many applications simply following the IC manufacturer's recommendations and/or employing simple rules of thumb are more than adequate to create a reliable functioning device.

The inductor don't "know" that there is a decoupling capacitor. There will still be some current provided through the inductor, and a (small) resulting voltage drop. But without the capacitor, the voltage drop would be far bigger.
If we completely remove the capacitor, and the inductor tries to supply all the current change, the V_inductor = L * di/dt is very big (if dt is small as in your simulation), so your voltage drops a lot.
If you add a big enough capacitor, as soon as there is a small voltage drop, the capacitor will start to discharge, providing "a lot" of current: so most of the (very short duration) current changes are supplied by the capacitor, the inductor providing only a small part of it.
For your simulation:

a 1 mH inductor is a HUGE inductor, specially if you are talking about parasitic inductance of traces (a value in the tens of nH or hundreds would be more likely)
your big oscillations are because of your high inductance, and the absence of resistive element to dampen then. Maybe try adding a few milliohms/tens of millioms in series with your inductor, to simulate the resistivity of your trace
increase the frequency of the current changes: decoupling capacitors are more intended for the 100 kHz+ frequencies
then you can start playing with the value of the capacitor: you can try something like a few pF (to simulate just the parasitic capacitance), or values in the 0.1-10 µF range (typical decoupling capacitors)



as soon as there is a small voltage drop, the capacitor will start to discharge, providing "a lot" of current :---this is it, which event is happening first? Shouldn't the cap not let voltage drop at all?


both happen simultaneously. If a capacitor supplies current, it discharges, and its voltage drops. If current increases in the inductor, the voltage drop across the inductor increases. As you can only have a single voltage VF1, the share of both effects can be calculated.

@needbrainscratched On an instantaneous basis, yes. Which if you look closely at your waveforms, you'll see the dV/dt of an ideal capacitor is always well defined, even though your test current step might have infinite dI/dt. That is, the voltage does not change instantaneously.

I think you've come quite far actually. The next step is to extract the practical result.
Sudden changes in load will be seen as high frequency from the supply's perspective. And you can think of the tank as if it is "resisting" to this change.
Now you have an equation (I didn't check if the equation was correct or not, though). If I'm not wrong, you can define how much drop in V1 voltage is allowed (or acceptable, if you wish) for how sudden changes in current.
In practice, the step current can be re-written as the sum of sine waves with different frequencies (Fourier series). The high-frequency components form the rising and falling in current (you know, no signal can have zero rise or fall time). You have frequency-dependence in your equation, looks useful to me.
As a side note, as indicated in another answer, the inductance is not realistic for a PCB trace in practice. We are talkin about nanohenries (nH). So a few tens of nanohenry combined with a few hundreds of nanofarads would have been a more realistic tank.

That model is not accurate enough even for a first order analysis.
First of all, there is no output impdance of the source or copper trace resistance. You always have some dampening losses instead of a pure LC oscillation tank circuit.
Second thing is, the used values are not realistic. The inductance might be in nanohenries and bypass cap maybe 100nF. And the load might be an IC like a MCU, consuming maybe 30mA on average, but it might run at 8 MHz or 500 MHz, so it consumes a very large and very narrow pulse of current at each clock tick.
Also there are other small inductances at play - for example the internal wiring inside the capacitor or load. So no matter how close the capacitor is to the load, the stray inductance inside the capacitor makes any capacitor useful only up to some frequency.
